# listview reusable component - architecture - android

Tags: android, android-listview, code-reuse

i have a complex view which contains 4 list views arranged as per the requirement. i have been been able to implement and get it working. but this is a sole activity and data needs to supplied internally (within the activity).
i want to define a way where in, this complex view is like a reusable component which is called by other activities that provide data for all 4 list views and then the view shows up in the screen.

could somebody please guide me as to how do i go about achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your listview structure in a layout file of its own. Then you can use whats called inflation, which lets you "inject" seperate layout files into your main layout in run-time. Take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Take note at the introductory notes. Android is already inflating an XML resource, namely the layout file you´ve defined in setContentView(), you can grab the current instance of the inflater and use it as you see fit, saving greatly on memory as opposed to instantiating it yourself.